# SIGNATURE_INVALID error in Tizen SDK 2.3.1

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-certificate

I've created an author's key and certificate in Tizen for wearables SDK 1.0.0 using the standard procedure and it worked well until I've switched to the new Tizen SDK 2.3.1 and tried to use the old certificate there. I've got "SIGNATURE_INVALID" error when was trying to deploy my app built in SDK 2.3.1 to an emulator (see a picture on the bottom).

Then I've tried to generate a new certificate in SDK 2.3.1 and to use it with the new application only, but it didn't work, because according to AppStore support, all applications should be signed by the same author's key.

Please let me know what the right way of certificate migration is. I would be hesitant to re-build the old apps in the new SDK and sign them with a new key, because quite a few of them have been already installed by users and I don't want to re-test and re-certify the old apps.

[image]

Comment: When you upload your app in the Tizen Store your certificate will be overwritten with Tizen Store certificate. I got following remarks on first trial when I uploaded the tpk file. (The applications which service through Tizen Store have to overwrite distributor certificate with Tizen Store certificate). This issue was resolved using Tizen SDK 2.3.0_Rev3 rev3 onwards.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer, but I'm having this error in SDK 2.3.1. This what I've tried lately: I've built and signed my new app in SDK 2.3.1 using the old cert/key generated in SDK 1.0.0. If you just build without deploying to the emulator, the error doesn't show up. I've submitted the app to App Store and it's "Under Device Test" now. It's pending in this state for 5 days by now. I'll let you know what the final result is when see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My new Gear S2 application has been finally approved by the Samsung App Store and this is how I did it. I've created two security profiles (see below): the first one is called 'gear' and points to the old certificate generated by the SDK 1.0.0. I use this profile only when I need to create and sign an application for the App Store. It works fine if you use "Build Package" command in Eclipse and don't run the app in the 2.3.1 emulator.

[image]
The second profile called "gears2" is used for developing and testing new applications in SDK 2.3.1 emulator. I think, it's a very good "workaround" that helps avoiding re-signing and re-certifying the old apps.

[image]